# Merging DataFrames with "uneven" data

Tags: python, pandas

Excuse the title, I'm not even sure how to label what I'm trying to do. I have data in a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
Name     Month     Status
----     -----     ------
Bob      Jan       Good
Bob      Feb       Good
Bob      Mar       Bad
Martha   Feb       Bad
John     Jan       Good
John     Mar       Bad
```

Not every name 'Name' has every 'Month' and 'Status'. What I want to get is:

```
Name     Month     Status
----     -----     ------
Bob      Jan       Good
Bob      Feb       Good
Bob      Mar       Bad
Martha   Jan       N/A
Martha   Feb       Bad
Martha   Mar       N/A
John     Jan       Good
John     Feb       N/A
John     Mar       Bad
```

Where the missing months are filled in with a value in the 'Status' column.

What I've tried to do so far is export all of the unique 'Month" values to a list, convert to a DataFrame, then join/merge the two DataFrames.  But I can't get anything to work.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Would you mind editing your post and showing us what you've attempted so far?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to take advantage of Pandas' [indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) to reshape the data :

Step1 : [create a new index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html#pandas.MultiIndex.from_product) from the unique values of `Name` and `Month` columns :

```
new_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    (df.Name.unique(), df.Month.unique()), names=["Name", "Month"]
)
```

Step2 : [set `Name` and `Month` as the new index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#set-reset-index), [reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with `new_index` and [reset_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to get your final output :

```
df.set_index(["Name", "Month"]).reindex(new_index).reset_index()
```

**UPDATE** 2021/01/08:

You can use the [complete](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.complete.html#janitor.complete) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/index.html); at the moment you have to install the latest development version from [github](https://github.com/ericmjl/pyjanitor):

```
 # install latest dev version
# pip install git+https://github.com/ericmjl/pyjanitor.git
 import pyjanitor
df.complete("Name", "Month")
```

Answer (score 5):

You can treat the month as a categorical column, then allow `GroupBy` to do the heavy lifting:

```
df['Month'] = pd.Categorical(df['Month'])
df.groupby(['Name', 'Month'], as_index=False).first()

     Name Month Status
0     Bob   Feb   Good
1     Bob   Jan   Good
2     Bob   Mar    Bad
3    John   Feb    NaN
4    John   Jan   Good
5    John   Mar    Bad
6  Martha   Feb    Bad
7  Martha   Jan    NaN
8  Martha   Mar    NaN
```

The secret sauce here is that pandas treats missing "categories" by inserting a NaN there.

Caveat: This always sorts your data.

Comment: Now that is interesting! I like the secret sauce. +1

Comment: Thanks.  The sorting breaks my real-life use case, but this is interesting for future reference.

Answer (score 4):

Do `pivot`

```
df=df.pivot(*df).stack(dropna=False).to_frame('Status').reset_index()
     Name Month Status
0     Bob   Feb  Good
1     Bob   Jan  Good
2     Bob   Mar   Bad
3    John   Feb   NaN
4    John   Jan  Good
5    John   Mar   Bad
6  Martha   Feb   Bad
7  Martha   Jan   NaN
8  Martha   Mar   NaN
```